# Apache tuning - Multiple WordPress installations

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp, fastcgi, dedicated-server

I'm running Apache2 server with multiple WordPress installations for my customers. I'm using FCGI-PHP & suexec. Server is dedicated 16GB RAM, Intel i5 2,6GHZ 4 cores. Server MPM: Worker. Network 100mbs.

I allow my WordPress users to upload files up to 100MB.
I have mod_pagespeed and mod_bw enabled. I have set bandwidth limit for each virtualhost to 1mbs.

I'd like to hear some tips how to tune Apache to that kind of use. I'm pretty new with dedicated servers. I have webmin installed but I don't have any analyzing app installed. What would be good moniter app to monitor server maybe with web browser? Also I'd like to hear how to setup my apache2.conf and cfgi-conf. Current is now:

```
Timeout 720
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 250
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          10
    MinSpareThreads      15
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          128
    ThreadsPerChild      100
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
 </IfModule>
```

FCGI configuration is:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 14
FcgidMaxProcesses 250
FcgidIdleTimeout 60
FcgidProcessLifeTime 720
FcgidIdleScanInterval 20
FcgidConnectTimeout 720
FcgidMaxRequestLen 131072000
</IfModule>
```

I'd be very happy if you could give me some tips/help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have http://newrelic.com/ on all my servers.

For Apache tuning this script gives hints for configuration
https://github.com/gusmaskowitz/apachebuddy.pl

For MySQL tuning this script gives hints for configuration
https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

You have more than enough available memory to run some heavy WordPress sites.
So I would use these tools and decide where to go from there.